# Multiple NSXMLParser get "BAD ACCESS"

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, exc-bad-access

i want to read a HTML File with this command:

```
parseHTML = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://theurl.com"]];    
[parseHTML setDelegate:self];
[parseHTML parse];
```

in the didStartElement method i want to stop the actual parser after he found a specified string and parse a new site with these information:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if(somethingfound)
    {
            [parseHTML abortParsing];
            parseHTML2 = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://theurl.com" stringByAppendingString:product_link]]];
            [parseHTML2 setDelegate:self];
            [parseHTML2 parse];
    }
}
```

i get an irregular error:

> Thread1: Program received signal: "EXC
>   BAD ACCESS"

any ideas?
regards

---

Hello Walter thanks for your comment, here is the complete implementation:
I hope it helps... :-/

> FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <ZBarReaderDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate>{

    UIImageView *resultImage;
    UITextView *resultText;
    NSString *product_link;
    NSXMLParser *parseHTML;
    NSXMLParser *parseHTML2;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *resultText;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet NSString *product_link;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSXMLParser *parseHTML;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSXMLParser *parseHTML2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;

- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped;

@end
```

> FirtViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDebug.h"

@implementation FirstViewController


@synthesize resultImage, resultText;
@synthesize product_link;
@synthesize parseHTML, parseHTML2;


bool link_is_here = false;
bool allergy_is_here = false; 
bool parse_one_ok = true;
int hoch = 0;


- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
{
    NSZombieEnabled = true;

    // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

    // present and release the controller
    [self presentModalViewController: reader animated: YES];
    [reader release];
}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{

    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        break;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    resultText.text = symbol.data;
    parseHTML = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://URL.de/suche/?q=" stringByAppendingString:symbol.data]] ]autorelease];
    [parseHTML setDelegate:self];
    [parseHTML parse];

//    [parseHTML release];

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
    resultImage.image =
    [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    for(NSString *key in [attributeDict allKeys]) {
        if ([[attributeDict valueForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"some_string"]) {
            link_is_here = true;        
        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"href"] && link_is_here) {
            product_link = [attributeDict valueForKey:key];

//            [parseHTML abortParsing];

            parseHTML2 = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://URL.de" stringByAppendingString:product_link]]];
            [parseHTML2 setDelegate:self];
            [parseHTML2 parse];
            parse_one_ok = true;
            link_is_here = false;
        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"id"] && [[attributeDict valueForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"other_string"]) {
            allergy_is_here = true;
        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"title"] && allergy_is_here) {      
            NSLog(@"DO:  %@",[attributeDict valueForKey:key]);  
        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"id"] && [[attributeDict valueForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"string"]) {
            allergy_is_here = false;

            parse_one_ok = true;
            NSLog(@"Parser off");
            //close all parser
        }
     }
}
-(void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    [parseHTML setDelegate:nil];
    [parseHTML2 setDelegate:nil];
    [parseHTML release];
    if (parse_one_ok) {

        [parseHTML2 release];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [parseHTML release];
    [parseHTML2 release];
    self.product_link = nil;
    self.resultImage = nil;
    self.resultText = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

hey my declaration is in the header:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>{
    NSString *product_link;
    NSXMLParser *parseHTML;
    NSXMLParser *parseHTML2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *product_link;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser *parseHTML;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser *parseHTML2;
```

and in the source:

```
@synthesize parseHTML, parseHTML2;
@synthesize product_link;
```

i get these exception in console:

> -[NSCFString setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1acad0

Comment: Can you post stack trace information about the crash?

Comment: Also the posted code seems to be missing important information, like the declaration of variables `parseHTML` and `product_link`

Comment: Do you have to do this simultaneously? Can you just store the data you found in an `NSArray` and parse the second file later?

Comment: yes, but how can i stop the parser correctly? (i want to stop it in the didStartElement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have to parse two files at once I set up a second delegate for the second file. The delegate is a simple NSObject that adheres to the NSXML Parser Delegate protocol. (It has the `parserDidStart`, `parserDidEnd`, blah blah blah).

Then in my `didEndElement` of my first parser I kick off the second parser with something like this

```
SoundCloudParser *scParser = [[[SoundCloudParser alloc] init]autorelease];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]autorelease];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:scParser selector:@selector(parseXMLUrl:) object:currentArticle.uriString];
[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

I do it on a separate thread which is why you have the queue in there. My 'parseXMLUrl:`looks just like a regular one, it just sets the delegate to my second delegate object instead of setting it to`self`.

One other thing you need to think about is that you are doing work at the `didStartElement` and I find that a lot of times I don't have any values in my parsing variables until I get to `didEndElement`. That would be something else for you to check.

UPDATE: In the future, if you are trying to build on something like ZBarSDK or another project, please say so. It would have saved me about half an hour of messing around with your code.
Basically what we need to do is to set up a new delegate. Let's call it `newDelegate`. Set it up as a regular NSObject and make it follow `<NSXMLDelegate>` protocol. It needs a mutableArray or a dictionary to store the data it will parse and it needs a function to kick it off. And that's about it.
So, let's assume you have created `newDelegate.h` and `newDelegate.m` in your project and in newDelegate.h you have
    #import "Your_App_Delegate.h"
    @interface newDelegate : NSObject {

```
NSMutableString *currentElement;
NSMutableArray *currentArticle;
}

- (void)parseXMLUrl:(NSString *)URL;
@end
```

So, now in your `didStartElement` you would call the newDelegate like this:

```
newDelegate *ndParser = [[[newDelegateParser alloc] init]autorelease];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]autorelease];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:ndParser selector:@selector(parseXMLUrl:) object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL.de/%@",product_link]];
[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

This would kick off the second parser and pass it the url to parse. You will need a way to get that data, so either store some results in your App Delegate or else change the parseXMLURL method of the second parser to return some value.

Comment: wow ok, this is very much information for me noob... can you describe it for my codeexample? that would be great!! regards

Comment: Assuming that your app is only an empty App Delegate and FirstViewController.m and FirstViewController.h why don't you post the entire contents of the two FirstViewController files. I don't have enough information to go on in order to help you. When I make a simple project that has your code in it as it currently appears, I don't get any errors and it does what you want (the first parser stops and the second one starts).

Comment: @Walter how can i get a return value?? NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]autorelease]; NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:ndParser selector:@selector(parseXMLUrl:) object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL.de/%@",product_link]]; [queue addOperation:operation]; [operation release];

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to put an NSDictionary or an NSMutableArray (or however you want to save the stuff that you parse) into your App Delegate. Then make it a property of the app delegate. Now you can reference the property from anywhere in your app as long as you have an #import "YourAppDelegate.h" and you use the `[NSApplication sharedApplication delegate]` pattern.

Comment: i have tried to copy values via [[operation result] getValue:&ParseAndCompare_result]; it works, but only with bool... after that i tried it with a NSmutableArray an it gives me an error: "[__NSArrayM getValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b0010"

Comment: From inside the delegate you will need to push the values back to the main program (so create a property on the Application delegate and set the values from within the delegate). The bool you are getting back only tells that the operation was successful or failure.

Comment: where i should these command:  [NSApplication sharedApplication delegate]? i have made a property of an NSmutabelarray.. an included the app_delegate.h

Comment: I usually to it in the "didEndElement" method. if your array is called "myArray" you would have something like [[[NSApplication sharedApplication delegate] myArray] addObject:tempVariable]; where tempVariable is whatever you are using to store an item you are parsing out of the main feed.

Comment: Sorry, [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]